# Which terms in the equations for dipole impedance include inductance/capacitance and velocity factor?

Tags: resonance, inductance, antennas

In the below equations for the impedance of a center fed half wave dipole, exactly which terms include self inductance/capacitance, and which terms cater for an antenna embedded in a homogeneous and lossless linear dielectric medium ?

[image]

Comment: suggest you post this on the amateur radio stack exchange and have Phil Frost answer it for you.

Comment: @nielsnielsen I already tried that and he doesn't know the answer.

Comment: Wow. he's the expert...

Comment: @nielsnielsen Yes Wow.